# Converting dates to numbers on Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I am trying to convert some of my data within a column of my Pandas data frame from the date format i.e 04-Jan to the int format i.e 4-1.

This is what the data in the column currently looks like.

0     04-Jan
1      0 - 5
2     01-Jan
3      3 - 0
4      0 - 0
5      0 - 3
6     03-Jan
7      0 - 0
8      0 - 1
9      4 - 0
10    02-Jan
11    01-Feb
12    01-Jan
13     1 - 0
14    03-Jan

And this is what I am trying to achieve.

0      4 - 1
1      0 - 5
2      1 - 1
3      3 - 0
4      0 - 0
5      0 - 3
6      3 - 1
7      0 - 0
8      0 - 1
9      4 - 0
10     2 - 1
11     1 - 2
12     1 - 1
13     1 - 0
14     3 - 1

I have tried using the DateTime module to covert it initially from 04-jan to 04-01 but was unsuccessful and I've also tried the str.split method but that is only splitting the data in the rows with integers.

Comment: Have you read any tutorials on this topic? Have you tried any methods they suggest there or here on SO? If so, which and why didn't they work?

Comment: the pandas docs are also very good, have a look at [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). you can cast your data to datetime using `format="%d-%b"` and then extract month and day.

Comment: Please share sample input with expected output for better understanding. Without that the question is likely to be downvoted and closed.